# Солсберский или солсберийский?

Tags: грамотная-речь, словообразование, прилагательные, суффиксы, выбор-варианта

Вопрос навеян двумя моментами.

1. Сегодня я услышала журналистский новояз (от города Солсбери) — ***солсберецкий*.**
2. Недавно я была в Латвии. Там есть город Юрмала, частями которого являются "бывшие" города **Дзи́нтари** и **Ке́мери** (теперь они входят в состав Юрмалы; соответствующие прилагательные — ***дзи́нтарский*** и ***ке́мерский***).

А каково же **правильное** прилагательное от города Солсбери — **солсберский** или **солсберийский**?

Comment: Кажется, это не журналистский новояз, а слово, употребленное одними известными сейчас интервьюируемыми...

Answer (score 2):

У меня есть подозрения, что латышский в данном случае нам не подсказчик и не ориентир, а ориентир как раз конечное *bury* в английском:

[Солсберийский собор](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%81%D0%B1%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B9%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80) (Salisbury Cathedral) — готический собор Девы Марии в английском городе Солсбери, который, будучи возведён в своей основной части всего за 38 лет, считается чистейшим образцом английской готики.

[Кентербери́йский собо́р](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B1%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B9%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80) (англ. Canterbury Cathedral) — готический собор в Кентербери. Официальное название — Собор и Митрополитская Церковь Христа в Кентербери (Cathedral and Metropolitical Church of Christ at Canterbury). Это главный англиканский храм Великобритании. Здесь расположена кафедра архиепископа Кентерберийского.